# How can I escape a JS variable when outputting PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, string, variables, escaping

How can I escape a JS variable when outputting PHP?

```
$output = '<script type="text/javascript">
               var myVal = jQuery(this).val();
               var myVar = <img src=\"myVal\" />
          </script>';
```

When I output this, `myVal` (javascript variable) is output as a literal string, not as a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings require quotes in javascript

```
$output = '<script type="text/javascript">
               var myVal = jQuery(this).val();
               var myVar = \'<img src="\' + myVal + \'" />\';
           </script>';
```

It's generally better practice to use a .js file, rather than outputting javascript directly with PHP.
Also note that `this` in the example would just be the `window`, which has no value

Comment: Don't they actually want myVal to be a variable reference in the img tag?

Comment: You have your closing `"` in the wrong place but this does work:

`var myVar = \'<img src="\' + url + \'" />\';`

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you looking for :

```
$output = '<script type="text/javascript">
               var myVal = jQuery(this).val();
               var myVar = \'<img src="+myVal+" />\'
           </script>';
```

*myVal is output as a literal string, not as the variable.* so you should concatenate the variable with the string using `+` sign.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `myVal` is the previous javascript variable and no a PHP variable. I Think, so this wont so as required

Comment: You should concatenate the variable with the string using `+` sign, check my update.